Iframe error while embeding SharePoint Online site into web application
I have a SharePoint Online site which I want to embed into my ASP.NET MVC web application using an iframe.
I am getting this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
MyDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/BlogSite.aspx?access_token=MY ACCESS TOKEN=embed:1

I have checked an online form which suggested a creating an Azure AD application then getting access token to my method and then embedding the Sharepoint site using iframe.
View page markup:
<div>
    <button onclick="login()">Login to SharePoint</button>
</div>
<div class="iframe-container" id="iframeContainer" style="display: none;">
    <iframe id="sharepointIframe" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
@section Scripts {
<script>
        function login() {
            const accessToken = '@accessToken';
            if (accessToken) {
                const iframe = document.getElementById('sharepointIframe');
                iframe.src = `https://MyDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/BlogSite.aspx?access_token=${accessToken}&output=embed`;
                document.getElementById('iframeContainer').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
}

Controller code :
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Model"].ConnectionString;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        var accessToken = await TokenService.GetAccessTokenAsync();
        ViewBag.AccessToken = accessToken;
        return View();
    }
}

public static class TokenService
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        var tenantId = "tenantID";
        var clientId = "ClientID";
        var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        var resource = "https://MyDomain.sharepoint.com";

        var requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", resource)
        });

        var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token", requestBody);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseJson = JObject.Parse(responseString);

        return responseJson["access_token"].ToString();
    }
}

I want to embed my Sharepoint site into my ASP.NET MVC web application using an iframe
